# Execution failed for task ':splash:dexDebug'

Tags: android-studio

I have a problem with android studio. I have imported an eclipse project but when I run this project, I get this error:

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

I don't know why I am getting this error. 
Please help me.  Thanks

Comment: What was the dependencies issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be due to some dependencies issue.
Remove the dependencies one by one and run the application.Then you can easily resolve this issue.

Answer (score 9):

**What causes the issue?**

> The Dalvik Executable specification limits the total number of methods
>   that can be referenced within a single DEX file to 65,536, including
>   Android framework methods, library methods, and methods in your own
>   code.

See [Google docs](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html).

**How to fix?**

Adding `multiDexEnabled true` in gradle.

```
  defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xyz.foo"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 17
        versionName "1.0"

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true

       }
...

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to enable multidex, see https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html and it seems a bug see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183811

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.